# Flutter project build fails after adding firestore dependency

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Build fails after adding firestore dependency with the error below:
This is only happening after adding the firestore dependency, when I remove it the app builds just fine.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
  >   Connect to 172.16.164.2:8080 [/172.16.164.2] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
  >   Connect to 172.16.164.2:8080 [/172.16.164.2] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.

Here is my global build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tola.www.tola"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

graddle wrapper properties:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

And my flutter dependencies:

```
    version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this build.gradle it has been working perfectly for me :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Hi @Testeur, I have tried that but its not building. Throwing same error but different gradle version:

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.

Comment: This is weird your error seems to say that it could not fetch your resources because it timed out. Do you have any internet restrictions on your network ?

Comment: It has worked. At first I assumed that since other plugins were getting installed fine, I expected firestore to get installed too. Following your recent comment, I double checked my connectivity and the problem was proxy settings. Though I disabled proxy in system settings, they were cached in gradle.properties in .gradle folder. So I removed the proxy entries there,  set classpaths in build.gradle as: 
_classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'_
_classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'_

Thanks alot.

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to close the question if it's solved.